# Precision fall to 3 digits with large numbers when converted to string

Tags: c#

I have the following number of type **double**

```
var a_number = 105229626666.6667;
```

When I stored it or convert it to a string the number get automatically truncated to 3 decimal places instead of "105229626666.667".

Is there a way to circumvent the issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use `decimal`. `var a_number = 105229626666.6667M`

Comment: A `double` is incapable of storing more than approximately 15 significant digits.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?force_isolation=true#use-standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
number.ToString("R");
```

---

The R stands for "round-trip":

> This format is supported only for the Single and Double types. The round-trip specifier guarantees that a numeric value converted to a string will be parsed back into the same numeric value.

See [standard numeric format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r) for more information

Comment: The `R` (round-trip) specifier contains some unfortunate implementation mistakes that have to be preserved for posterity to appease compatibility, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r) recommend against using it in favor of (in this case) `G17`.

Comment: this kinda works for this case, but it'll fail for other values because `double` can only be precise to 53 bis or ~15 digits

Answer (score 0):

a_number is not of type double but it is of type Decimal. To prevent truncation try following:

```
var a_number = 105229626666.6667M;
```

The literal with the m or M suffix is of type decimal.
For more information on this read below reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types